# How do I check for an index within a double array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

```
int[][] mytime = {
        {10, 33},  
        {11, 23},  
        {9, 13},  
        {16, 53},
};

for (int h=1; h < mytime[0]; h++)  // checking for the first index (ie: 10, 11, 9, 16)
for (int m=1; h < mytime[1]; h++)  // checking for the second index (ie: 33, 23, 14, 53)
```

How do I do a for loop till one of the index checks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by `one of the index checks`, but here's how you can get the numbers of the first and second columns:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mytime.length; i++) {
    int first = mytime[i][0];
    int second = mytime[i][1];
}
```

You have to iterate on the rows from `0` to `mytime.length-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something

```
int[][] mytime = {
        {10, 33},  
        {11, 23},  
        {9, 13},  
        {16, 53}
};

int[] firstIndex = new int[mytime.length];
int[] secondIndex = new int[mytime.length];
for (int h = 0; h < mytime.length; h++) {
    firstIndex[h] = mytime[h][0];
    secondIndex[h] = mytime[h][1];
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. Been doing a lot PHP lately so I get mixed up sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't show what you tried, and the result/failure you got. That would help people to better understand your issue.

```
public class TotoTo {
    public void foo() {
        int[][] mytime = { { 10, 33 }, { 11, 23 }, { 9, 13 }, { 16, 53 }, };

        for (int h = 0; h < mytime.length; h++) {
            System.out.println(mytime[h][0]);
        }
        for (int h = 0; h < mytime.length; h++) {
            System.out.println(mytime[h][1]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... params) {
        new TotoTo().foo();
    }
}
```

Note that in Java (as in many other programming languages, **array index starts at 0**, not at 1.

Also you have to be carefull with that kind of constructs: what if at some point in time the content of your mytime array changes? You could get an ArrayOutOfBoundException...

```
int[][] mytime = { { 10 }, { 11, 23 }, { 9, 13 }, { 16, 53 }, };
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to print all those values you've assigned. In that case, the following would be the code:

```
int[][] mytime={{10, 33},  
        {11, 23},  
        {9, 13},  
        {16, 53},
    };
    for(int h=0;h<4;h++)//for the rows i.e 10,11,9,16
    {
        for(int m=0;m<2;m++)//for the columns i.e 33,23,13,53
        {
        System.out.println(mytime[h][m]);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.